# Facebook SDK breaking Codeigniter? Blank page

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have tested my login script on my localhost with no problems.

I have now uploaded it online as can be seen at [this link](http://www.gua.com/account/login/)

Obviously if you click, you can see that a blank page is displayed and I have no idea why.

I did a test of a little bit of content, and removed the Facebook SDK code.

```
        //Facebook config (required for library)
    $fb_config = array(
            'appId'  => 'REMOVED',
            'secret' => 'REMOVED'
            );

    //Load Facebook library
    $this->load->library('facebook', $fb_config);

    //SET FACEBOOK USER 
    $fbuser = array();
    $fbuser = $this->facebook->getUser();
```

When the above code is not present, the page loads.

I have updated my app setting correctly, namely changing the site URL fro `http://localhost` to http://gua.com so i dont believe it is that.

I have even changed my CI settings to show all errors - nothing is shown.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the above code might be making a blank page load ONLY when it is hosted online?

Many Thanks
THomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up the base_facebook.php and try removing either of these two lines from the top.

```
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')) {
      throw new Exception('Facebook needs the CURL PHP extension.');
    }
    if (!function_exists('json_decode')) {
      throw new Exception('Facebook needs the JSON PHP extension.');
    }
```

If you stop getting the white screen, it should indicate that your sever needs either curl or json_decode enabled.

Alternatively you could just do a `echo phpinfo()` and check if they are enabled. Note that json_decode/encode is only available in php >=5.2

Answer (score 0):

If your localhost was a Windows box and your remote host is a *NIX system, there is a chance that some extra white space was introduced into your SDK files outside of the `<?php ?>` tags. This can sometimes cause the "white screen of death" when this whitespace is output and sets the headers.

Try downloading a fresh copy of the SDK from Github and don't unzip it until it is on your remote server. Better yet, if you ssh access `wget` it or `git clone` it directly there. See if that helps.

If it doesn't, add `error_reporting(E_ALL)` as the first line of your script and see if that tells you anything.

Comment: My localhost is running on Linux Mint, and my server on Ubuntu..?
None the less, I will try it and report back.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run chmod eg: "sudo chmod -R 777 facebook/". I think the files were written in or for windows so on a *Nix system it does not run till that is checked.

In my case after doing this, I started to have errors I could work with.

Comment: 777 seems _very_ permissive. Surely there is a more subtle value to pass to chmod?